# How to set scanResponse in startAdvertising() in Android L for advertising data as a peripheral

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, peripherals

As described in the API reference in Android L which is available here: https://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html

There are two ways to start advertising data in Android L using Bluetooth Low Energy:

> 1. public void startAdvertising (AdvertiseSettings settings, AdvertisementData advertiseData, AdvertiseCallback callback)
> 2. public void startAdvertising (AdvertiseSettings settings, AdvertisementData advertiseData, AdvertisementData scanResponse, AdvertiseCallback callback)

The second method contains one more param: scanResponse

When I use the first method, everything works fine, and I could scanned the information set in the advertiseData. However, when I test the second method, I could only scan and get the data in scanResponse, and from the LogCat, I got the following error:
[image]

[image]

It seems to be a bluetooth buffer issue, and in my (advertise)callback object, I log a sentence:

```
advertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AdvertiseSettings advertiseSettings) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Adv Success");
                // Other operations
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i) {
                // Other operations
            }
        };
```

It can be seen from LogCat that the onSuccess() method is called twice, and I think it could be either of the following two reasons:
1. advertiseData and the scanResponse data, while the advertiseData may have caused the bluetooth problem, thus it could not be broadcasted;
2. advertiseData is closed (successfully) after it starts (successfully) (probably);

Did I use this method in a wrong way? I use the Nexus 5 with Android L Preview edition, or it is the bug for the current Android system?

**Reference**:

> **Method**: public void startAdvertising (AdvertiseSettings settings, AdvertisementData advertiseData, AdvertisementData scanResponse, AdvertiseCallback callback)
>
> Start Bluetooth LE Advertising. The advertiseData would be broadcasted after the operation succeeds. **The scanResponse would be returned when the scanning device sends active scan request**. Method returns immediately, the operation status are delivered through callback.
>
> Requires BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
>
> Parameters
>
> settings   Settings for Bluetooth LE advertising.
>
> advertiseData  Advertisement data to be advertised in advertisement packet.
>
> scanResponse   Scan response associated with the advertisement data.
>
> callback   Callback for advertising status.